# Synchronize the Background Color on a TabBar/NavigationBar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I have a simple app with 4 Tabs. All of them contain a `UINavigationbar`, on which I placed some `UIBarButtons`. One of the `UIButton` will change the Background color at some point - this can happen on any Tab. Now, I want to inform the other navigation controller, so they can set the backgroundcolor of the Button to the same color. The user should see the same color on all the tabs.

What I did so far: I created a super class which creates the buttons within the `ViewDidLoad` method. But... what now?

Any ideas?

By the way,I develop for iOS > 4.0 with Xcode 4.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inform you superclass about color change using protocol. If you new in this topic i would suggest you watch this [youtube - protocol](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1nbH7v6gMPg)

Answer (score 1):

You can use either of KVO / NSNotifications / custom delegate pattern.

-MANN